# Problem when running sass after installation

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-modules

**THE PROBLEM**

I'm trying to run sass as part of a course I'm doing. However, when inputting the following command:

`PS H:\Qubo\LEARNING\HTML & CSS\CSS\sass_sandbox> npm run sass`

I get this:

````
> node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive

'CSS\CSS\sass_sandbox\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'H:\Qubo\LEARNING\node-sass\bin\node-sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sass_sandbox@1.0.0 sass: `node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sass_sandbox@1.0.0 sass script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-08T20_44_40_258Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: Either run `npm i` if you got node sass as a dependency or run `npm i -g node-sass` and try again

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? I'm grateful, thanks. J

Comment: What happened when you did what I suggested?

Comment: Sorry Dominik, I posted my comment before seeing your comment. I'll try now

Comment: I tried both, neither worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, albeit I don't exactly know how it works.

SOLUTION:

1. Looking at the code, I noticed that it had a problem finding a folder, which was not in the folder is what looking for.
2. It was looking in 'C' when my folder was in H (a separate hard drive).
3. I moved it to the desktop (inside 'C') and presto, it worked.